# how do i refer to the subject $(this) from a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/), i just get undefined as my get values?

```
$('.banner').colorbox({
    opacity: 0.4,
    href: 'dialogs/ban_add_edit.php?banner_to_edit='+$(this).attr('id')+'&typeofbanner='+$(this).attr('rel')            
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.banner').each(function() {
  $(this).colorbox({
    opacity: 0.4,
    href: 'dialogs/ban_add_edit.php?banner_to_edit='+this.id+'&typeofbanner='+$(this).attr('rel')            
  });
});
```

In your current code `this` refers to whatever you're running this in, probably a `document.ready` function (so `this` = `document`).  In this version, you're looping through `.banner` elements, and `this` refers to the element you're on as you loop.

One more change is `this.id`, I often do this to, but no need for `$(this).attr('id')` unless you need to handle it being chained later...`this.id` raw DOM style is shorter and faster :)

Comment: worked a treat, thanks for the tip on using the this object too

H

Comment: @J-P: I don't think IE likes it.